# what is the tiniest windows client tool that will allow auto-upload files to hosting

Tags: windows

I am looking for a small tool that will allow me to do one single tiny simple job :

- auto upload files from local computer with Windows(xp/vista/7) to hosting (linux servers with cpanel)

There are probably tons of tools on the internet, but i dont' want to install anything on client computers that will allow them to browse or advanced functionalities and i don't like to install bloatware with features that will never be used

So i would appreciate your personal feedback and preferences, if you can tell me about the simplest and smallest tool outhere to auto-find new files and upload them to pre-defined location on hosting.

Thanks !

Comment: You should probably say what version of Windows is on the client machines and what protocols are available on the server.

Comment: thank you for suggestion - specified the local computer and server types - fair ?

Answer (score 1):

The tiniest windows tool to allow automated uploading is probably FTP.

Here's a guide that I found: http://www.brettb.com/ScriptingWindowsFTP.asp

Essentially, you create a text file containing the things you would type by hand:

```
 open ftp.servername.com 
 username
 password 
 get default.asp
 quit
```

Then save that and run it (or schedule it) thusly:

```
 ftp -s:FTPcommands.txt
```

Of course, this is contingent on your hosting service allowing FTP.

Comment: ohhh lovely suggestion ! pretty nice indeed, any idea if i can get the status of upload (if completed or no so i can archive or rename the already uploaded folders ? )

Comment: Sadly, I don't know of a way, but then I'm not a huge Windows person, either. Very possibly someone may comment who knows, or you could ask it as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

On which end would you want to know the status?  I'm not sure how you would know on the server end how big the file is supposed to be from the client end and therefore able to determine if the transfer was successful.

On the client side, you might be able to use the return code of the scheduled task to determine if the transfer was successful but that's a bit iffy as well.

Maybe your best bet would be to make your script file a little more complicated and write the results to a variable and have further processing in the script that would rename if the results are successful.

Comment: Also take a look at wget and cURL to see if they offer upload features.  There may be some additional functionality in them over the dumb Windows ftp client.

Comment: Thanks keith - well i thought about not re-inventing the wheel - i tried to do something with vb.net - but was not working as well 
here is the post on stackoverflow

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170994/uploading-files-to-server-in-vb-net-my-computer-network-uploadfile-gives-417

If you have any sample code that would allow file upload, would appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: I don't look at StackOverflow but found a post there regarding PowerShell, which is noticeably more powerful than the standard Windows command interpreter.  Let's see if the machinery lets me include a link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936108/how-to-script-ftp-upload-and-download  If not, it's question 936108.

Also take a look at WinSCP.  It has lots of commandline and scripting options.